# How to implement autocomplete dropdown box in asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am looking for a sample code where a dropdown box in asp.net webform is made to be autocomplete with the data coming from a sqlserver. I see lots of sample code which implements such extension on a textbox but not on a dropdown box. It can be implemented either with pure jquery and an asmx webservice or using AjaxControlToolkit.

Thanks